# Python: How to load and use trained and pickled NLTK tagger to GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle, nltk

I have a trained and pickled NLTK tagger (Brill's transformational rule-based tagger).
I want to use it on GAE. What the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your NLTK tagger code and data is of limited size, then carry it along with your GAE code.

If you have to act upon it to retrain the set, then storing the content of the file as a `BLOB in the datastore` would be an option, so that you get, analyze, retrain and put.But that will limit size of dataitem to be less than 1 MB because of GAE hardlimit.

Comment: Could also use the file interface to the [blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to write new data that's larger than 1MB.

Comment: Not in a static dir! Static dirs are served directly to the user and inaccessible by code. Instead, include it in your app and _don't_ mark it as static.

Comment: @Nick - I thought Static Dir was accessible readonly by code (What if we pointed the location directly via url). But anyways as you point and I realize that they would be served by CDNs, it would be bad idea to store them in static dirs.

Comment: No - static dirs are explicitly _not_ accessible by code. All files that aren't marked static are accessible; static is for files that should be served directly by the frontend.

Comment: Now we have cloud storage api for GAE.